# how can i add fb_multi_friend_selector, Facebooker2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebooker

Hi i want to add to my app multi-friend-selector.
I found a method in helpers: fb_multi_friend_selector.

Am i supposed to do just:

```
 <%= fb_multi_friend_selector("Test message") %>
```

Because it is not working for me. My user is authenticated in my app. I can see all of my fb friends names(with current_facebook_user.friends)...etc. So i am logged in. And i have the permission :perms => 'publish_stream'.

What should i do to get fb_multi_friend_selector working?
I am using rails 2.3.5. And facebooker2 with mogli gem.
Thank you very much for any answers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try sticking this in your view:

```
    <fb:serverFbml>
        <script type="text/fbml">
            <fb:fbml>
                <fb:request-form
                    method='POST'
                    type='an invitation to do this.'
                    content='I invite you to do this.  
                        <fb:req-choice url="http://apps.facebook.com/smiley/yes.php" label="Yes" />
                        <fb:req-choice url="http://apps.facebook.com/smiley/no.php" label="No" />'
                    <fb:multi-friend-selector actiontext="I invite you to do this.">
                </fb:request-form>
            </fb:fbml>
        </script>
    </fb:serverFbml>
```

Comment: the form shows up all right with all my friends in it. i choose them and i submit the form. it redirects me to some facebook page where again i can see this same form. but no effect on facebook(no invitation is send to a friend i choose to invite). hm. thans for answering anyway.