# Facebook multi friend selector not working in RoR application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, api, multi-friend-selector

I tried to implement the Facebook multi friend selector in my Ruby on Rails application.
The FB login has already been done. I tried to paste [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3832373/how-can-i-add-fb-multi-friend-selector-facebooker2) code into my view it but doesnt seem to be working.

```
   <fb:serverFbml>
        <script type="text/fbml">
            <fb:fbml>
                <fb:request-form
                    method='POST'
                    type='an invitation to do this.'
                    content='I invite you to do this.  
                        <fb:req-choice url="http://apps.facebook.com/smiley/yes.php" label="Yes" />
                        <fb:req-choice url="http://apps.facebook.com/smiley/no.php" label="No" />'
                    <fb:multi-friend-selector actiontext="I invite you to do this.">
                </fb:request-form>
            </fb:fbml>
        </script>
    </fb:serverFbml>
```

I can see the Loading indicator which comes in Facebook, but it seems to be there forever.
Is there anything I am missing here? Pls help!

Comment: This seems to be FBML, which has been deprecated I think. I am sharing the code that I have used to post on wall and Invite friends using a multi friend selector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 <div id="facebook_invites" class="conclusion" style="width: 750px; text-align: center">
    If you like <%= link_to "BillBaba.com", "/", :target => "_BLANK" %>, then please help us by spreading the word.<br/>
  <a id="wall_post" href="#" style="font-size: 2em;">Post on your Wall</a><br/>
  <a id="invite_friends" href="#" style="font-size: 1.5em;">Invite your Friends</a>
  </div>
    <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      $('#wall_post').click(function() {
        FB.init({
          appId:'<%= @app_id %>', cookie:true,
          status:true, xfbml:true
        });

        FB.ui({ method: 'feed',
          link: 'http://www.billbaba.com',
          picture: 'http://www.billbaba.com/images/logo.gif',
          description: 'There is so much more to life, other than bill payments. Try BillBaba.com and never miss another bill payment.',
          name: 'BillBaba.com'});
      });

      $('#invite_friends').click(function() {
        FB.init({
          appId:'<%= @app_id %>', cookie:true,
          status:true, xfbml:true
        });

        FB.ui({ method: 'apprequests',
          message: 'There is so much more to life, other than bill payments. Try BillBaba.com and never miss another bill payment.'});
      });
    </script>
```

Here @app_id is the application id being passed from the controller.

Comment: Is there any facebook documentation on this, from where I can read more?

Comment: You can find it here: http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/464/
  and here: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/channels/#requests